# Gradient from transparent to color in CSS

Tags: html, css

My Boss give me an image (please see below) and told him I would make his site look the same.  Here is my code, but it doesn't look like the image:

HTML

```
<div class="clearfix" id="footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/pages/facility">Become a Virtual Active Facility</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/about">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="/pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, white, white) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    width: 914px;
}
```

[image]

How can I get the result to look the same?

Comment: because I don't know effect do it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? `opacity` should do it in many browsers. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why not just make the transparent bar in an image creator program?

Comment: @Pekka I think he wants a transparent gradient that starts with nothing and ends in white.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: I will try test

Comment: @Pekka: Kyle Sevenoaks explain for me. Thanks Kyle Sevenoaks

Comment: @Kyle make that an answer, that is the best solution I think (because CSS gradients don't work cross-browser yet)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your gradient is defined as going from 'white' to 'white'. In other words, there is no gradient.

In the final 2014 syntax:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white);
```

Note that prefixed versions (moz-, webkit-, o-, etc) use a different syntax, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: This will work on Firefox 3.6 / Thunderbird 3.1 / Fennec 1.0 and up, since it's Mozilla-specific code. His only problem was that the code didn't do what he wanted, so I am not assuming he needs help in making it cross-browser. If it needs to work on all browsers, he has another problem coming because not all webbrowsers are graphic to begin with...

Comment: @KevinCampion that's because it was non-final syntax which has changed. I've updated the answer to use the final 2014 syntax.

Comment: I'd add that some browsers do not pre-multiply alpha channel... and what does this mean? That transparent areas (which have color, but alpha channel at 0%) actually leak their colors. `transparent` is actually `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` (transparent black), and the result is some black leaking on the transparent edge (the left edge). **The bottom line: for the effect the OP expects, I'd rather use `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` (transparent white).**

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, transparent, white) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use alpha (rgba) look at that, may help you: [CSS3 Transparency + Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293910/css3-transparency-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
                left,
                rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%,
                rgba(201,201,201,1) 50%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 100%
                );
```

I use it to add some fade effect on both side of my hr