# How to feather the edges of an image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, insets

I have an unordered list containing 3 list items. Each list item has an image, and 3 divs containing text. I want the edges of the image to be feathered, by using only CSS.

My site [found here](http://testsite24.byethost17.com/temp/index.html) currenly has a feathered effect by using the following html for the image. However it seems to make the whole image feathered, instead I only need the very EDGES to be strong feathered, and then become less feathered as it spans approx. 50px towards the center on all sides of the image.

HTML:

```
<p class="vignette"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg" alt="" /></p>
```

CSS:

```
p.vignette {
  position: relative;
}

p.vignette img {
 display: block;
 width:80%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:6%;

}

p.vignette:after {
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 180px #defeec;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 180px #defeec;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 180px #defeec;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 2;
 content: "";
}
```

You can see I'm using an inset box shadow of 180px but this makes the whole image feathered slightly, and if I use say 50px it is barely noticeable at all! How do I make just the edges strongly and then fading into weaker towards the center?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the vendor prefixing on box-shadow anymore.

Comment: It should be working now. It's off/on

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964794/soft-edges-using-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change some stuff around to get this to work. First, take inline-block off the `<a class='divLink'>` tag. Then try the following:

```
.vignette {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 113px #defeec inset,-50px -50px 110px #defeec inset;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then use the following html (and scrap the `<img>` tag)

```
<p class="vignette" style="background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg);"></p>
```

Of course, you could also put the `background-image` rule inside the css block, but sometimes declaring a background image inline makes a lot more sense, especially if you expect to have a number of photographs or similar.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I think I've applied what you've said correctly, however the green boxes now appear to have a green border AROUND them. I need the image edges to bleed into the color of the box surrounding it. I've linked to a perfect example below, where you can see the photo's edges bleed into the beige color around it. That's what I need done but the edges need to be green, like the list item box. The second link is my demo site with your changes applied. Thanks for any feedback!

http://testsite24.byethost17.com/temp/screenshot.png
 http://testsite24.byethost17.com/temp/index.html

Comment: The fiddle is showing me a feather effect across the entire image, not just the borders though? That house should be clear and it's edges should bleed into the green... perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @Nova Right, you need to adjust the 50px values that are set on the box-shadow rule. Make them smaller for less fade, larger for more fade. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: @Nova Take off the `margin-right:50%;margin-left:50%;` and replace it with `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;` or `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @Nova Also, you can add as many of the `box-shadows` as necessary to get the fades where you want them. just separate them with commas like: `box-shadow:x y blur color, x y blur color, x y blur color` etc.

Comment: Awesome Jake, thanks for the detailed support! Take care

Answer (score 0):

Create a div that would go inside `vignette`, and call it `fade`. It must go above the `img` though.

```css
.fade {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position:absolute;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
                    rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, 
                    rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
                    rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
                    rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%
        );
    }
```

```html
<p class="vignette">
        <div class="fade"></div>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg" alt="" />
    </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments! Eric, how exactly do I apply a class to another? Do I simply do this in the css?     p.vignette fade{ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,
                rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%
    );
}

Comment: By altering your HTML: `<p class vignette fade>`

Comment: No, you want `<p class="vignette fade">`

Comment: Ok, I now have the html: <p class ="vignette fade"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg" alt="" /></p>    and added the  class p.vignette fade beneath the previous vignette code, but it doesn't seem to change anything. The result can be seen in my demo link above.

Comment: Making a few edits to my answer, I'll post it shortly.

Comment: The updated answer has you creating a div that would sit above the image and create the effect. `vignette` already has `position: relative` so you're good there.

Comment: I've applied the changes you made, and assuming the css ".fade" should actually be "p.vignette fade" because it's within the vignette class, I think I've done what you said. However, this has only stretched my image and there's no feathering effect visible. If you view the source of my demo page above, perhaps you'll see something wrong in the HTML or CSS. I'm at a loss...