# Prevent gradient overlay from scrolling

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-gradients

I am trying to put a small gradient on the bottom of a scrolling div.  I've based my solution on the accepted answer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204450/how-to-apply-a-fade-away-effect-not-animation-across-all-the-content-of-a-div).  The gradient shows up fine, but when I scroll the content in the div, the bottom of the gradient moves.  I need it to remain in place so that the content scrolls independently of the gradient.  I've tried several combinations of `position: fixed`, `position: relative`, and `position: relatve` to no avail.  What have I missed?

Relevant markup:

```
<div class="resultListContainer">
    <ul class="result">
        <li><span class="resultPermitNumber resultElement">B123456789</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultPermitType resultElement">FINAL</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultDisplayAddress resultElement">41975 LOUDOUN CENTER PL SE, LEESBURG, VA 20175</span></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Lots more of the ul. -->
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.resultListContainer {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 400px;
    width: 40em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.resultListContainer::before {
    background-image: linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 95%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    content: "\00a0";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.result {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

The result:

[image: The gradient stop scrolls.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your container in another div that is positioned as relative.

Also, overlay will block your scroll bar, so instead of `width: 100%` I used: `left:0; right: 16px;` - now scroll is clickable.

Try my fiddle: 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/8c6k4k6d/1/

Comment: The answer provided by @somethinghere is awesome and in-depth and taught me a few things, but @Kocik directly answers my question (for example, @somethinghere changes the structure of my layout to have just one `<ul>`).  I wish I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 4):

Because your element is positioned `absolute`, it's position is absolute to the parent element so when you scroll it scrolls *with* your content. What you want is your `ul` to scroll. I have quickly rewritten yours, but below I've got a simplified and cleaned up version:

```css
.resultListContainer {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 400px;
    width: 40em;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.resultListContainer::before {
    background-image: linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 ) 95%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 ) 100% );
    content: "\00a0";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.result {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.result li {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultListContainer">
    <ul class="result">
        <li><span class="resultPermitNumber resultElement">B123456789</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultPermitType resultElement">FINAL</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultDisplayAddress resultElement">41975 LOUDOUN CENTER PL SE, LEESBURG, VA 20175</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultPermitNumber resultElement">B123456789</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultPermitType resultElement">FINAL</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultDisplayAddress resultElement">41975 LOUDOUN CENTER PL SE, LEESBURG, VA 20175</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultPermitNumber resultElement">B123456789</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultPermitType resultElement">FINAL</span></li>
        <li><span class="resultDisplayAddress resultElement">41975 LOUDOUN CENTER PL SE, LEESBURG, VA 20175</span></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Lots more of the ul. -->
</div>
```

Basically there are two things that are important: your outer box *cannot* be scrollable, you inner box can. All the fixed elements need to be *outside* your inner box (which is your `ul` in this case). Secondly, your `:before` cannot be `100%` high, as it will absorb your mouse events, preventing scrolling. For all browsers except IE you can solve this by using `pointer-events: none`, but otherwise the safest way is to make your gradient a fixed height and your `:before` element the height of the gradient you want, resulting in a (in this case) `20px` area that would not take your mouse events at the bottom.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; } body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

div:before, div ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

div:before {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* IE does not support pointer events, so making this small in height is important
  as your scroll events will not be passed to the ul if it is covered by your :before */
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

div ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1;
}

div li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ececec;
}

div li:nth-child(2n){
  background: #cecece;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
.resultListContainer::before
```

with

```
.resultListContainer .result:last-of-type::before
```

Comment: This one exchanges the gradient for a large white empty area after the last `ul.result`.