# Gradient overlay on element on the right side

Tags: css

I have created a container with elements that is scrollable. I want the element on the right side to have a gradient overlay. How can I create that with CSS?

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 1000px;
}

.element {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/RjZGaM

Comment: U mean that the elements which are in red color should be replaced with gradient overlay?

Comment: only the one that is furthest to the right

Comment: Do you mean something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802412/1961144

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent gradient overlay from scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801932/prevent-gradient-overlay-from-scrolling)

Comment: An overlay over all elements as well: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOvxYX (just in case, you know, anyone might be found wanting)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are just looking for the last element to have a gradient color, you can code your css like this:

```css
   .container {
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 1000px;
}
.element {
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-right: 10px;

  }
.element:last-child
{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, grey, white);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, grey, white);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, grey, white);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, grey, white);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
   <div class="element">
  </div>
   <div class="element">
  </div>
   <div class="element">
  </div>
   <div class="element">
  </div>
   <div class="element">
  </div>
 <div class="element">
  </div>
 
 
 
</div>
```

[Check updated codepen](https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/xPLMaQ)

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the div element you want to add the gradient style

```
.element {
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , white); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, white); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, white); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red , white); /* Standard syntax */
}
```