# making jqm collapsible transparent

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, stylesheet

I have a jquery mobile collapsible and I want to make it transparent

I tried following style, but was in vain

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xPzwM/6/)

When I use

```
background: #557700;
filter: alpha(opacity=30);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30);
opacity:0.3;
```

Entire collapsible div including selectbox inside become transparent.

How can I solve this so that only background of collapsible is transparent.

**EDIT**

This is what is used to get it work

```
$('#my_collapsible').find('div').first().css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)','color':'white'})
```

Don't know if this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is class **ui-btn-up-c** which is creating problem. In this class there is already background gradient is applied because of which you are not able to experience transparency.

```
.ui-btn-up-c {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(241, 241, 241, 0.5)) repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE; /* Add something like this*/
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

This will help you: [CSS3 Transparency + Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293910/css3-transparency-gradient)

Comment: yes. so i need to select the child div and change its style. and not directly the style of collapsible