# CSS gradient, transparent colors in IE?

Tags: css

Can I use transparent color with gradients in IE?

I've tried

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=transparent, endColorstr=red);
```

Oddly, this creates a gradient from blue to black, even in IE9.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293910/css3-transparency-gradient

Comment: Yes. It gives an example of an extended hex for opacity, but doesn't explain the logic. So I still don't know how to get transparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
#000000FF
```

so:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#000000FF, endColorstr=red);
```

And, not tested, but I hear that 0 works as well. Then it's startColor, not startColorstr.

Comment: And if you're using a pre-processor such as LESS you can convert to ARGB format: argb(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)) . We used this to write a mix-in helper for supporting IE8 & 9.

Answer (score 9):

There's no mention for "transparent" value being supported by `(start|end)ColorStr` attribute. For Internet Explorer 8 and below you can try the following code:

```
.transparentGradient {

    /* The element needs layout */
    zoom: 1;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
        gradientType=1, startColor=0, endColorStr=#FFFFFF
    );
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
        gradientType=1, startColor=0, endColorStr=#FFFFFF
    );
}
```

Here's [**a working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JMtM5/embedded/result/). I have tested it in IE8, its compatibility mode, and in IE6.

## startColor / endColor

The `startColor` and `endColor` parameters accept:

> **Integer** that specifies or receives the color value that can range from
>   **0 (transparent)** to 4294967295 (opaque white).

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532929(v=vs.85).aspx

## startColorStr / endColorStr

You can also use a `startColorStr` or/and `endColorStr` which accept:

> **String** that specifies or receives a value that can range from #FF000000 to #FFFFFFFF.

So you can specify the colors in "#RRGGBB" (as in the example) or "#AARRGGBB" formats, the latter being defined as:

> Color is expressed in #AARRGGBB format, where AA is the alpha
>   hexadecimal value, RR is the red hexadecimal value, GG is the green
>   hexadecimal value, and BB is the blue hexadecimal value. The alpha
>   value controls the opacity of the object. **An alpha value of 00 is
>   transparent, while a value of FF is opaque.**

The default value is `#FF0000FF` (opaque blue) and if you pass a value that is out of range then it defaults to it. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532930(v=vs.85).aspx

---

Don't forget that:

> An object must have layout for the filter to render.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx