# <div> with 2 backgrounds using css sprites

Tags: html, css-sprites

my question looks a little bit crazy but, can i make such a thing as the shown below in this [picture](http://i37.servimg.com/u/f37/11/89/27/52/untitl10.jpg),
am thinking of too many possibilities
i am 100% aware that i can do :

```
<div id="TheContenaire">
<div><div> <!--this is where i can put a background image or a gradient style using css-->

<div></div> <!--the same thing with this div-->
</div>
```

but can i do this with just one div (TheContainer) and apply two backgrounds for it using css sprites and just one image ?
put it on top, then again on bottom and rotate it
or any other manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `linear-gradient` then there is no need for layered elements: http://jsfiddle.net/e8gyb/

To layer something without another element use `:after`

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

A good article on gradients: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/
Some more demos: http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/

Edit: that will work on IE10+, for IE6-9 you will need to use `:after` with this: [CSS gradient, transparent colors in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663569/css-gradient-transparent-colors-in-ie)

Comment: i think boxshadow gives the same effect as for linear-gradient  
but it's more practicable because you don't have to bother yourself with browsers compatibility

Comment: `box-shadow` works with IE9+, `linear-gradient` with IE10+ unless you use `:after` with `filter` and `-ms-filter` which will give full support from IE6+

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

An inset shadow option:

```
div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4em 7em -4em #000000,
                inset 0 -4em 7em -4em black;

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HcXsm/1/)

Or with `background-image` and `gradient`:

```
div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#000), to(transparent));
    top: 0%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 3em;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(transparent), to(#000));
    top: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 3em;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HcXsm/)

Obviously you'll have to use whichever vendor prefixes are required for your implementation.