# Why is my navigation background not changing the opacity?

Tags: html, css, navigation, opacity, photoshop

I made a Photoshop image for a fixed navigation background, so that is it somewhat see through. I changed the opacity on a gradient in Photoshop cs6, but as a placed the background on the navigation, it stayed solid and I could not see through it at all. Why is this happening? do I need css to change the opacity or can I just use the image.

here is the background code:

```
        background-image: url(images/navBackground.png);
```

Comment: Is the image you saved definitely just the background gradient and nothing solid behind it?  Saved as a transparent png?

Comment: Yes I made sure it's a png

Comment: and here is the code:     background-image: url(images/navBackground.png);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity in photoshop doesn't show when uploading to web.  It remains 100% opaque just less vibrant.  You would need to alter the opacity of the image with css using the opacity property.

Comment: is there a way to make a gradient opacity meaning it's not the same in all spots. I want to have a glass like effect.

Comment: Yeah, totally. I would utilize the background-color: rgba(r, g, b, a), where a is opacity value between 0-1.  As in graphic design, I would just overlay a div to give it that glass effect.  Here's a good post related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293910/css3-transparency-gradient

Comment: It doesn't remain opaque.  If so, how does this work: http://jsbin.com/OrIjaHe/1/edit