# Can I create gradient line effect with css or html5?

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I don't want to use  an image for this. I want to create a line which from transparent towards solid with css. Can I? with css3 or html5 as like this;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: http://codepen.io/richbradshaw/pen/uexaG

```
.blurred-line {
  height:30px;
  width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;

  -moz-background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, black 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, black 100%);

  border-radius:15px;
  -webkit-filter:blur(1px);
}
```

Which renders like:

[image]

Despite what most people seem to think, that gradient syntax is the real syntax, and works in Firefox 10+, Chrome 26+, IE10+ and Safari 6 (or 7?)+.

Including all the ancient gradient stuff is a waste of time, unless you are planning to support browsers that don't exist (e.g. Chrome 10, Firefox 3.6).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a horizontal linear gradient with border radius, something like:

```
border-radius:50px;
background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkTam/) or the snippet below for more details.

```css
.rounded {
    height:50px;
    width:80%;
    
    border-radius:50px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 0, 0 0, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded"></div>
```

---

There is a gradient generator that i like a lot since it gives crossBrowser solution called "[Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)".

Answer (score 0):

Use rgba format

```
/* webkit example */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)),
  to(rgba(80,80,80,0.2)), color-stop(.5,#333333)
)
```

An example: http://nicolahibbert.com/css3-alpha-transparent-gradients/

Duplicate: [CSS3 Transparency + Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293910/css3-transparency-gradient)

This tool might be helpful too: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

As you said **"from transparent towards solid"**, this should be what you want:

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="gradient">
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    /*background-color: #791;*/ /*uncomment this property to see the transparency effect*/
    padding: 10px;
}
div.gradient {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,1)); /* use vendor specific property if the standard one does not work */
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with CSS3, and if you want it to look just like the image you provided, you can use some transparency and border-radius. I always found [this link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) helpful: