# Gradient: half color half transparant

Tags: css, gradient

I have this line of code

`background:linear-gradient(341deg, #8a8a8a  0%, #8a8a8a  31.9%, #000 32.1%, #000 100%);`

As you can see its half grey half black. Is there a way to make the grey part of it transparant, so then it would be half transparant half black..

Thanks in advance, 
Kevin

Comment: replace the color which you want to be transparent with `transparent`

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/a/14609591/6263942

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rgba()` to achieve this where the first 3 parameters are the color you want (in your case, `138, 138, 138`) and the last parameter is the opacity (in your case this will be 0)

To give you an example, your code will turn into this:

```
background:linear-gradient(341deg, rgba(138,138,138,0)  0%, rgba(138,138,138,0)  31.9%, #000 32.1%, #000 100%);
```

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znnrjbrb/1/) you can see it in action

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
background: linear-gradient(341deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .33) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 31.9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 31.9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
```

Check the result

```css
.original {
  background:linear-gradient(341deg, #8a8a8a  0%, #8a8a8a  31.9%, #000 32.1%, #000 100%);
}

.advice {
background: linear-gradient(341deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .33) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 31.9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 31.9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}

.original,
.advice,
.tree{
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.tree {
  background-image: url('http://glebkema.ru/images/2015_09_20_iphone_155_x400.jpg'); 
}
```

```html
<div class="tree"></div>
<div class="tree"><div class="original"></div></div>
<div class="tree"><div class="advice"></div></div>
```

Comment: I love that you used an image in your example, since that's the main thing I'm trying to achieve on my website. this is very welcome thanks.

Comment: @KevinAartsen Thank you for your feedback. It inspires me to become better.